# undefined local variable or method ruby

Tags: ruby

I recently bought a book that helps a beginner learn ruby.  We are building our 1st program and I cannot run the script through terminal without getting an error.
All i'm trying to do is open a file.

Here are the details:
The script file is simply:

```
file.open("text.txt").each { |line| puts line }
```

This script is saved as analyzer.rb and saved in my ruby file called "ruby".

The text.txt file is a plain text file that has the first chapter of oliver twist, nothing special.  It is also saved in the ruby file.

Here is what I am typing into terminal to simply run the script:

```
cd ~/ ruby
ruby analyzer.rb
```

Here is exactly what I get.

```
Hunters-MacBook-Pro:ruby huntermaxfield$ ruby analyzer.rb
analyzer.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `“text' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I have tried to manipulate the code in all sorts of ways, but since I am a beginner it really is just a guess.  Any help would be great.

Comment: It seems you have a typo in your code, instead of `"text.txt"` you have `“text` or like by the error message.

Comment: I don't thin the code you have pasted in is actually the code you are running in `analyzer.rb`. There's no way for the code you've pasted int to raise that exception.  Perhaps you have forgotten the quotation marks in your actual `analzyer.rb`, different from what you've pasted in here? Although when you say "it is also saved in the ruby file" I am not sure what you mean, and that sounds potentially problematic as well. But if `analyzer.rb` really consisted only of that one line you show us, exactly like that, there's no way you could be getting that error.

Comment: Ah, took a closer look at your error message -- I think you have "curly quotes" in your source file (but not in the one you've pasted in here). They can't be curly quotes,they need to be straight quotes. Don't try to use MS Word to write code, it's asking for pain. Turn off curly quotes in whatever editor you are using, or get an editor actually designed for writing code. SublimeText is a good one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see a minimal sample of the code you are running that replicates the problem. As is, the code you show can not replicate that error. As others commented, `“text` doesn't exist in your code. Without that code we are merely shooting in the dark, guessing at what the problem could be which is hardly a good way to help you.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback!  I got it to work using shivam's code that I copy and pasted.  I am just using textEdit for now.  If I download SublimeText, will that fix my issue?

Comment: Also, I just disabled the smart quotes feature in text edit, does anyone know if that does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `File` 'F' should be in capital. That's the mistake

```
File.open("text.txt").each { |line| puts line }
```

Also make sure "text.txt" is in same directory as you ruby script, else provide absolute path like `File.open("absolute/path/to/text.txt")`

Comment: I just changed that, but I'm getting the same exact error.

Comment: @HunterMaxfield did you try the absolute path?  Also check your `""`s

Comment: I just tried the absolute path.  I typed in exactly what you provided, I get the same error, except now the error is with absolute:                    undefined local variable or method `“absolute' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: What would I check with my " "s?

Comment: NO! absolute path means full path to your file. `absolute/path/to/text.txt` was just for example. It will be different for your file

Comment: It's located in my ruby folder, which is the same folder as analyzer.rb.  I changed my code to: ("ruby/text.txt") and now it gives me the same error, except ruby is in the quotes.

Comment: try copy pasting this as it is: `File.open("text.txt").each { |line| puts line }`

Comment: that worked!  thanks!  What was different about your code than mine?

Comment: I suspect you were using some different character than `"`. Thats why I emphasized earlier to check your `""`s

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on page 84 (Beginning Ruby; From Novice to Professional) of Peter Cooper's book. I definitely recommend using Sublime instead of TextEdit that I initially used. 
It is all about using REGULAR QUOTES in the code, not smart quotes. Moreover try not to copy paste if you are not sure of your editor!